# input from file on server prompt

Tags: c, linux, netcat

When a TCP connection is established to the server, it prompts a question and waits for an answer for 3 seconds in while loop and then terminates. I need to send contents of the file to the server as a response to a prompt -  so I would want to put them on the stdin.

I absolutely must wait, server first needs to ask a question and then I need to send result from a file back.

Is there a way to accomplish this task with pipes and netcat or something similar? Or do I have to adjust some basic tcp client program for my needs?

*Edit* Background: For a university assignment I need to overflow the buffer to get access to the server. I have constructed a string that does that successfully for the precompiled binary now I need to send that to the server. Simple copy paste wouldn't work since my string contains unprintable characters or characters that if encoded result in different hex values.

*Edit* Logfile for cat file | nc host port

[Logfile](http://pastebin.com/LNv8TUkX)

Comment: Do you need to wait for the server to send its prompt or can you just assume that it will send the prompt and send the data right away?

Comment: Yes, I need to wait for the prompt and then send the contents of the file as a response

Comment: Can you add what you wrote in the comments to your question? The two points "you absolutely must wait" and "I need to make calculations based on what the server sent" are very imporant (and render shell utils useless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with a simple shell pipe, as the flow through pipes is unidirectional. You can build loops with pipes, but not in a single command, and at that point, I’d just go for a simple TCP client application written in a programming language of your liking.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want transfer one file from client to server throw netcast.

So 
in the server side you can do: 
nc -l 3333 > myfile.txt

and in the client side
cat myfile.txt | nc localhost 3333

But I don't understand when you say "When a TCP connection is established to the server" actually it means nothing.

Comment: My problem is that I have no control over server. Server doesn't accept anything right away it first prompts for the input (it asks for a sum of 2 hex numbers), and I then must insert contents of a file as a response. so if I do cat file | nc <host> <port> the result is in the logfile in the post above.

Comment: It looks like a homework problem! They ask for a hex sum as a test that you are doing from code, use something like [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication) Aslo you can resolve the sum by your self or show the first message and as for the input.

Comment: Now I see that I'm right is for a homework. Important Are you sure that you need to do the overflow after the prompt, or you have to use the answer string to cause of the overflow in the processing of the answer?

Comment: I solved it, wrote a simple python script to send a file after a prompt. Yes its a simple buffer overflow assignement